# How to get number of items per row in Listview in winjs

Tags: listview, winjs, windows

My app is responsive so, number of items per row changes according to size. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to get number of items based on win-itemscontainer width.

In my case, each item is of 158 px width + 5 px margin. So, item occupies 163px.

Now to get number of items,

```
var numberOfElementsPerRow = Math.floor(document.querySelector('.win-itemscontainer').offsetWidth / 163);
```